# dealing with custom CA

Tags: docker, proxy, ssl-certificate

I am having trouble dealing with custom certificates of my corporation. More specifically, they use zscaler and have a man-in-the-middle proxy which intercepts all connections. I use a docker image from another company which makes different API calls however I get SSL errors due to the mitm proxy.
Classic attempts on my host like

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

are not successful.

Mounting my local directory via

```
sudo docker run -v /etc/ssl/certs:/etc/ssl/certs anothercompany/latest
```

also does not work.

I tried searching but am not finding many resources/solutions to this AFAIK rather common requirement.

Only other option I found is to make a custom image based on the anothercompany image, add the cert within it and `update-ca-certificates`. However this seems very cumbersome as I'd need to rebuild on every release and push to a artifact repo in my company for usage.
Overwriting the entrypoint has the same issue as above.

Am I going down the wrong rabbit hole?

How do you handle these situations? Are there common best practices I am missing?

Thanks a lot for any pointer.